# ANTLR parser for EBNF grammar and get a decomposition tree with results

Tags: tree, antlr, parser-generator, ebnf, decomposition

I’m trying to make a lexical parser to compute all solutions given a EBNF term.
For example:

**Grammar:**

T::= nil | A.T | (T+T) | (T*T)

A::= a | b | c | d | e

**Operators:**

* Exclusive OR

. Sequence

+ Parallel

**Symbols:**

a b c d e

**Example term:**

a.(b+c).(d*e)

**Computed term:**

[image: Computed term]

**Expected tree output:**

[image: Solution tree]

The solution should be all tree branches.

My question is that which will a optimal approach for doing this?

For now i want to user ANTRL to build the grammar parse tree.

But im not very sure on how to make the refactor approach to compute the term.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading and researching on how to solve this problem, I realized that this situation is pretty much similar to a finite state machine, and there are a lot of software design patterns to deal with the solution.

So forth the update will be.
Define the algorithm as a finite state machine using one of these models

[Python finite state machine](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FiniteStateMachine)

Now, the next step will be on how to process each state as a parse tree (Ill try to use ANTLR), to get the next possible states.

So forth, does anyone know which would be an optimal solution to parse and process a term like a EBNF expression? i.e. using ANTLR?

Cheers.